# Saving fragment UI state after detach called

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment, lifecycle

I am working with a UI using tabs in the ActionBar.   When switching between tabs I am currently managing the Tab click events in my Activity and am calling attach and detach as needed using FragmentManager.

Each time a Fragment is attached I am going through the full lifecycle and creating a new view and loading all my data over again.   I am using the given Bundle in onSaveInstanceState and onActivityCreated to update gui elements (mainly the scroll position of a list).

This is working OK, but has lots of overhead.  In my case the list may have 300 or so records and there is a noticeable delay when switching between tabs.

In an effort to speed things up I am now saving the root view in onCreateView as a class variable.  Then when onCreateView is called again as a result of the fragment being attached I test for a non null value for my root view and return it instead of re-inflating the view.  This saved view still has the appropriate data set and I also bypass loading the data in this case.   Of course I still need to fully rebuild the view and data if the Fragment is destroyed by OS while in the background.

My question is if this is a valid approach?  I don't see a downside to it unless there are memory issues to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best approach, and here's why:

When you create the root view the first, all views are inflated using the `Activity`'s context. If this `Activity` ever gets destroyed, and then you attempt to reattach the `Fragment` to a new instance of this `Activity`, you will have issues.

Secondly, it's a terrible use of memory to have a fully inflated root view sitting around when it's not being used. Now, the records you mention are not stored in any `View`, but rather your list view has a reference to an adapter you created, which is keeping that adapter in memory along with your views. That is a lot of data to just have sitting around.

Now to properly give you a recommendation, you ultimately have to draw a line between memory usage and performance, keeping in mind that if you plan to make this app public, there are a LOT of inferior hardware devices.

One option is what you have already done, which is to make use of the `savedInstanceState` variable when being detached. You can try putting your 300 records in this `Bundle` and see how that performs. If the data is a class you have created, implement the `Parcelable` interface (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to know how to properly implement this) and store it in the `Bundle`, and then retrieve it later and create a new adapter. I would highly advise against keeping references to `View`s between attachments.

Comment: Thank you for the response.   I have seen others suggest hiding a fragment instead of calling detach but would assume this creates about the same memory overhead as my solution.

Comment: I need to finalize the look and feel of they actual fragment.  Once all the styles are complete I will look at the memory being used by the view and make a decision based on that.   Are there any guidelines for acceptable memory use for a given API level?

Comment: It's going to depend on device hardware, not the device OS version. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) article if you haven't before.

Comment: Taking the advice here I am taking the route of optimizing for memory over responsiveness.  In my tests so far, creating the view over again is acceptable with a typical data set.